# Weird space in footer only in single.php when there are comments?

Tags: bug

I have an extremely **weird problem** and I cannot figure out what's going on.
I REALLY hope someone here might have a clue or else I don't know what to do anymore.

So, there's a weird space gap in my footer like so:
[image]

I've done a lot of testing already and here's what I got thus far:

This **ONLY happens in the single.php** when there are already comments. It doesn't happen on any other page or in the single.php without comments.
It also doesn't happen when there are several pages with comments.
Ok, more testing. It seems to happen only on a few single.php pages. I cannot figure out yet what those articles have what others don't. An article where it happens for sure is this one: http://zoomingjapan.com/travel/top-3-night-views-in-japan/

It's **NOT a CSS issue**. Even with an older CSS style version of my backup where this didn't happen yet, it still occurs. 
Also, the CSS has loaded completely and the footer doesn't have that weird gap yet, then the site continues loading and only then the gap appears. It's clearly something else in Wordpress causing this.

It's also **NOT a plugin** as it also happens when all plugins are turned off.

It **doesn't seem to happen in IE11** (on Windows 7), but it happens in Firefox and Opera. (I didn't test more.)

***What on earth is going on?***
Any clues? Anything I could do to find out what is causing that gap only when there are comments?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to what @Flamenco mentioned it has to do with the **Video Download Helper** add-on.
NOW, when I put the following into my CSS I can see that something is added via Javascript.

```
.vdh-mask {
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Looks like this:
[image]

You can go ahead and browse around to test yourself. I also didn't find any clues in the source code of my blog: http://zoomingjapan.com/

Comment: Which page is it? I can't find the bug.

Comment: Do you run LastPass browser extension by chance? I am seeing what you describe being caused by runaway div with icon from it.

Comment: @ManojKumar I noticed that it doesn't happen on all pages. I've included a link to an article where it happens for sure in my question above. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Rarst I don't think so. Never heard of it. So, does that mean a floating div is causing that? I haven't touched my single.php or comment.php in a while. Gotta check them again.

Comment: I guess it is a browser issue? Because it's fine from here.

Comment: @ManojKumar What browser did you use?

Comment: Firefox 38.0.1. Try disabling all your extensions and check?

Comment: It doesn't happen for me on article you linked to. It's probably some strange interaction between theme styling and something else.

Comment: @Rarst It didn't happen until yesterday. I did change quite a bit in the footer (html and css) yesterday. But even if I insert an old CSS the problem persists. Maybe the html in the footer is causing it then?

Comment: @Rarst Replaced with a very old version of my function.php HTML. Same issue. So, it's not that, either. I'm really running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to what Flamenco mentioned I figured it out.

If you have the same issue just put the following into your CSS:

```
.vdh-mask {
position: absolute;
}
```

The gap is caused by the add-on "**Video Download Helper**". There's nothing we can do about it, but at least it can be hidden via CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the Video Download Helper in your browser, try disabling that, and it will likely disappear. If it does, this also explains why it's not on every page. Not every page will have that type of media, and what's tricky is that it will not show up in View Source at all. Also if true, that means that you can't really fix it if someone is using a similar plugin.

Comment: Woah! You are right!
But that doesn't explain why it also happened in my mobile Opera browser - and why it didn't happen until recently or on other blogs I'm browsing.
Still thanks so much. At least it doesn't seem to be (completely) my fault. ;)